# How to define the menu-title for a custom post type?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I used `register_post_type()` to create custom post type.

My problem is that the title of my first sub-menu item is the name of the post type. **How can I define a custom title for the menu item?**

```
add_action( 'init', 'myofferlugin' );

function myofferlugin() {

    $labels = array( 
        'name' => _x( 'My Plugin', 'offer' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Meno one', 'offer' ),
        'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'offer' ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'My Plugin', 'offer' )
    );

    $args = array( 
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'supports' => array( 'title' ),
        'menu_icon' => plugins_url('images',  __FILE__).'/icon.png',
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post'
    );

    register_post_type( 'offer', $args );
}
```

Comment: Sorry didn't get your problem ?

Comment: my plugin creates left sidebar menu =>"Meno one" with submenu name also "Meno one", i want sub menu name to be "something else" not "Meno one"

Comment: Where and how does your submenu get its name?

Comment: I edited the title and question to be more clear. Also fixed some grammar.

Answer (score 4):

I am not 100% sure if this is what you mean, but to edit the submenu label for custom post types the label to edit is "all_items". For example:

```
'menu_name' => 'Books'
'all_items' => 'All Books'
```

Would give you a main navigation label of "Books" and the sub menu items would be "All Books" and "Add New".

See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type for the full list of labels